# Absolute value bound of Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, inequality, lebesgue-integral

For the Riemann integral, we have the bound $$\left|\int_Af(x)dx\right|\leq\left(\sup_{x\in A}|f(x)|\right)\cdot\left|\int_Adx\right|$$

Do we have a similar bound for the Lebesgue integral, one like

$$\left|\int_Af(x)d\mu(x)\right|\leq\left(\sup_{x\in A}|f(x)|\right)\cdot\left|\int_Ad\mu(x)\right|?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, only $\sup_{x\in A}|f(x)|$ should be replaced by its [essential supremum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum). The proof can be seen, for example, in [Natanson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1258648318), Chap. 5.